# Google grant app permission pop up dialog callback

Tags: android, accountmanager, google-authentication

I am using **AccountManager** to obtain **auth token** as shown below

```
public void loginUser(Account userAccount) {
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    accountManager.getAuthToken(userAccount, AUTH_SCOPE, null, this,
            new OnAuthTokenAcquired(), null);

    this.currentFragment.onUserAccountSelected(userAccount);
}

private class OnAuthTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {       
    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
        try {
            Bundle bundle = result.getResult(); 
            String accountName = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            String authToken = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

            showProgressDialog(null, getResources().getString(R.string.logging_in_user_msg));
            getHouseholdMemberManager().loginUser(accountName, authToken, User.AuthType.AUTH_TOKEN, "google-oauth2",
                    MainActivity.this);             
        } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {                                
        } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
            onGoogleSignInError(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {             
            onGoogleSignInError(e.getMessage());                
        }
    }
}
```

When an user clicks on google sign-in button an account picker dialog opens /not shown/. Once an account is selected **loginUser()** is called, the user is presented with Google grant app permission pop up dialog and prompted to grant the app permission to view basic profile info. 
The problem is when the user clicks OK button, **OnAuthTokenAcquired.run()** is not called. He must click sign-in button again in order to obtain the auth token which I find quite incovenient.

Could you please assist in finding the way how to pass control to **OnAuthTokenAcquired.run()** when the user dismisses app permission pop up dialog by clicking OK button?

Comment: Can't directly answer you question but give this a try - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/815900/Android-social-network-integration This works ok with G+ and FB. Anyway the multi-social-networking is a better solution.

Comment: @Stan Thanks will have a look at it.